# lvm physical volume set not allocatable after server move to virtual machine. Can I change it?

Tags: lvm

I have a virtual machine running on LVM. Its working ok except that now I can't expand or create any logical volumes. It gives me the error:

```
# lvcreate -L10G -n test LocalVG
 Insufficient free space: 320 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

But I have much more than that available to the volume group:

```
# vgdisplay LocalVG
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               LocalVG
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  13
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                9
  Open LV               9
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               299.84 GB
  PE Size               32.00 MB
  Total PE              9595
  Alloc PE / Size       6656 / 208.00 GB
  Free  PE / Size       2939 / 91.84 GB
```

And the cow image on which this vm is residing is 300MB and is on a filesystem on the host that currently has 101GB free.  So it shouldn't be failing.  I did notice that the physical volume that the VG uses in the VM is set to unallocatable:

```
# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vda2
  VG Name               LocalVG
  PV Size               299.85 GB / not usable 6.83 MB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              9595
  Free PE               2939
  Allocated PE          6656
```

Maybe this is normal, but my other hosts show their PVs set allocateable = yes.  So my questions are, should I be running "pvchange -x y /dev/vda2" on this PV or is there something else wrong?  Can the host be online when I do this?  Does the PV have to be allocatable in order for an LV to get extents from a VG?

Comment: Well as a follow up, I just tried changing the PV to allocatable that fixed the issue. No problems that I can see from making that change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this was a while ago, but at the time I tried switching the PV to be allocatable as shown above and that fixed the issue. Its been two years since then and I haven't had any further issues. Must have been an obscure bug. Hopefully this info will help someone in the same boat someday.

You can mark a physical volume as allocatable with `pvchange`.

```
# pvchange -x y /dev/volume
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be allocatable, but try using the **lvresize** command with the -l (small L) option and after add the number of Free PEs you want to give to it.

Something like this :

```
# lvcreate -l 2939 -n test LocalVG
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this would have changed anything.  Using a MB or GB value with -L probably just converts to extents in the program before actually expanding since that's what it actually works with, so its the same difference.  Anyways, I've been using it after I fixed it above (note my comment) for months now and its been fine.