# vgdisplay shows free extents but lvresize doesn't find them

Tags: filesystems, lvm, partition

I'm trying to grow a LVM logical volume, and resized the physical volume. Now, vgs shows free extents, but when I try to assign them to the logical volume with `lvresize`, it says `0 extents available`.

### Setup details

The system uses a btrfs, which is in a logical lvm volume inside of a physical LVM partition that is encrypted with LUKS. Originally, the whole file system was 1.35TB large, I now resized that to 1.45TB by growing the LUKS partition in gparted, then running `pvresize` to resize the physical LVM volume in it. Afterwards, trying to run `lvresize` to assign the space to the logical volume is where I failed.

### Logs

```
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/luks-[some-id]
  VG Name               data
  PV Size               <1.46 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              382667
  Free PE               28001
  Allocated PE          354666
  PV UUID               [some-id]
   
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo pvs
  PV                                                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree   
  /dev/mapper/luks-[some-id] data lvm2 u--  <1.46t <109.38g
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               data
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <1.46 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              382667
  Alloc PE / Size       354666 / 1.35 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       28001 / <109.38 GiB
  VG UUID               [some-id]
   
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree   
  data   1   1   0 wz--n- <1.46t <109.38g
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                data
  LV UUID                [some-id]
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time recovery, 2020-09-08 08:42:57 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                1.35 TiB
  Current LE             354666
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
   
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root data -wi-a----- 1.35t
```

First attempt - resizing it to max available space - just doesn't change anything:

```
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo lvresize -l+100%FREE /dev/data/root
  Size of logical volume data/root unchanged from 1.35 TiB (354666 extents).
  Logical volume data/root successfully resized.
```

Attempts at manually resizing it say there are no extents available

```
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo lvresize -l+28001 /dev/data/root
  Insufficient free space: 28001 extents needed, but only 0 available
recovery@recovery:~$ sudo lvresize -L+100g /dev/data/root
  Insufficient free space: 25600 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

But the `vgs` and `vgdisplay` commands above clearly showed free available extents. Any ideas what could cause this and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: [lvm physical volume set not allocatable after server move to virtual machine. Can I change it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/238974/lvm-physical-volume-set-not-allocatable-after-server-move-to-virtual-machine-ca)

In summary, for some reason that I don't understand, the physical volume got set to `allocatable=NO` and changing that to `YES` via the following and worked

```
$ sudo pvchange -x y /my/physical/volume
```